# Collected data in collection erased on external excel close - excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have a vba code in one excel which reads data from many other excel at a specific location, but data gets vanished on external excel close

below gives the code which affects the collection after the line

```
Workbooks(fileName).Save
Workbooks(fileName).Close
```

Code:

```
Sub filefindermacro()
    Dim directory As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim datecollection As New Collection
    Dim majorcategory As New Collection
    Dim projectname As New Collection
    Dim partname As New Collection
    Dim username As New Collection
    Dim designerchecker As New Collection
    Dim fpactualhours As New Collection
    Dim ractualhours As New Collection
    Dim currentstatus As New Collection
    Dim softwareused As New Collection
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    directory = "D:\cam\UserExcel\"
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

    Set projectname = New Collection

    Do While fileName <> ""
        i = i + 1
        j = 2
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
            If sheet.Name = "HAI" Then
                Dim counter
                counter = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                For i = 3 To counter
                    datecollection.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 1))
                    majorcategory.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 2))
                    projectname.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 3))
                    partname.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 4))
                    username.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 5))
                    designerchecker.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 6))
                    fpactualhours.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 7))
                    ractualhours.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 8))
                    currentstatus.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 9))
                    softwareused.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 10))
                    'MsgBox projectname(i - 2)
                Next
            End If
        Next sheet
        **Workbooks(fileName).Save
        Workbooks(fileName).Close**
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Dim projectfile, projname
    projectfile = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "")
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To projectname.Count
        'MsgBox projectname.Count
        **If projectname.Item(i) = projectfile Then**
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 1) = datecollection(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 2) = majorcategory(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 3) = projectname(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 4) = partname(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 5) = username(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 6) = designerchecker(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 7) = fpactualhours(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 8) = ractualhours(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 9) = currentstatus(i)
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 10) = softwareused(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Since the source and destination sheets have the same structure, you could use a single collection and  `myCollection.Add sheet.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 10).value` and in reverse `Sheet1.Cells(j, 1).Resize(1, 10).Value = myCollection(i)`

Comment: @TimWilliams, i can understand you but that's not my exact problem, my problem is when i close the excel where i collected the data, the collection variable loses its data too.

Comment: I can't see from your code how that could happen unless the workbook with the code saved and closed *itself*

Comment: have the code trail in a excel, so that you will be finding my issue exactly, since the code sounds good to read or analyze but doesn't work is the problem here! @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed it earlier but here is your problem:

```
projectname.Add (sheet.Cells(i, 3))
```

What are you actually adding to the `projectname` collection when you do this?

You might expect it to be the cell's value (since that's the default property of `Range`), but *you're actually adding a reference to the cell itself*, and once you've closed the source workbook, you can no longer access that.

Here's the fix:

```
 projectname.Add sheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
```

Another reason never to write code which uses default properties without explicitly including them...

And you don't need the `()` here.

Comment: i think the problem is fixed, lemme check once with my code and will let you know the fix, thanks for the help!